# Как правильно написать: «рейтинг лапшЕЙ» или «рейтинг лапшИ»?

Tags: лексика

**Контекст**

Купили пять пакетиков лапши/лапшей быстрого приготовления. Надо их попробовать, составить рейтинг и озаглавить его: «Рейтинг лапши» или «Рейтинг лапшей».

Answer (score 3):

У "лапши" нет множественного числа. Цитирую [отсюда](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1147-1172.html):

§ 1150. К словам, лексические значения которых препятствуют выражению отношений "единичность – множественность", принадлежат следующие (приводятся существительные в их основных значениях; в отдельных случаях слова, употребляющиеся, как правило, в ед. ч., могут образовать формы мн. ч., но при этом изменяется их лексическое значение; см. ниже).

*1)* Вещественные существительные, называющие то, что поддается измерению, но не счету: вино, вода, горох, железо, вермишель, крупа, ***лапша,*** масло, мед, медь, молоко, пшено, сено, серебро, соль, цемент, чугун, шерсть, а также вещественные существительные с суф.­ ин(а), ­ик(а): баранина, осетрина, земляника, черника.

*Лапша* неисчислимая, то есть можно *взять 200 г лапши,* но нельзя *взять 5 или 10 лапшей.* Поэтому последняя форма не существует в языке.

Таким образом, правильно: *рейтинг лапш**и**.*

Ещё хотел отметить одну мелочь. Вы пишете "надо их попробовать", то есть, как я понял, *пакетики.* Конечно, в разговорном языке иногда так упрощают, но правильнее сказать так: "Надо попробовать лапшу из каждого (или: всю лапшу перепробовать), составить рейтинг..." Ведь пробуем-то мы всё-таки её, лапшу. ;)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Comment: *Да не за что)*

Answer (score 0):

Ещё, по идее, должен быть по правилам РЯ верным и вариант "лапш"
Каша - много разных каш.
Лапша - много разных лапш.
:))